# How to build a shared and a static library without recompiling the sources with CMake

Tags: compilation, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to build both a static and shared version of the same library as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam). However, the sources are compiled twice, one for each version which is not necessary. 
Any ways of avoiding this ?

Comment: Why not create a "shared" wrapper around your "static lib"? Of course, this all depends a bit on the usecase...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How can I build a shared and a static library without recompiling the sources twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899582/cmake-how-can-i-build-a-shared-and-a-static-library-without-recompiling-the-sou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the platform. On Linux at least, you need to use different compiler flags to produce [position-independent](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (shared library) than ordinary (program or static library) code.