# Building both static and shared libs for LLVM libc++ 3.3

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, libc++, cpack

The latest LLVM `libc++` 3.3 from SVN comes with a `CMakeLists.txt`. I am a CMake newbie, but yesterday I studied enough to be able to build `libc++` check-out on a RHEL 6.4 x86_64 host.

In addition, I was able to add enough `CPack` related commands in said `CMakeLists.txt` to generate a `libcxx-3.3.svn-0.el6.x86_64.rpm`.  But very likely due to being new to `CMake`, I can't build a static and a shared lib at the same time.

Yes. I reviewed [Is it possible to get CMake to build both a static and shared version of the same library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam). But, instead of using the `add_library` and enumerate all source files, I would like to use the approach employed by `libc++`'s `CMakeList.txt` - using `APPEND`.

I could generate a static lib by replacing the `ON` in line 40 below with `OFF` to build a static lib

```
40  option(LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED "Build libc++ as a shared library." ON)
41
```

Or I could leave it as is and build a shared lib.

I also tinkered with the following lines, eliminating the `NOT` or commenting out lines 232 and 233 for example. But regardless what I tried, I just couldn't seem to get the static lib to build together with a shared lib.

```
232  if (NOT LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED)
233    list(APPEND LIBCXX_CXX_FEATURE_FLAGS -D_LIBCPP_BUILD_STATIC)
234  endif()
```

How can I adjust the `CMakeList.txt` file so as to build both at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I decided to use the "tried and true" method of using a `add_library` command, with all `*.cpp` listed. It works OOTB, so I consider it a solution.

I will re-visit this issue again once I have time to improve my proficiency with `CMake`.