# How to create a shared library with cmake?

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, shared-libraries

I have written a library that I used to compile using a self-written Makefile, but now I want to switch to cmake. The tree looks like this (I removed all the irrelevant files):

```
.
├── include
│   ├── animation.h
│   ├── buffers.h
│   ├── ...
│   ├── vertex.h
│   └── world.h
└── src
    ├── animation.cpp
    ├── buffers.cpp
    ├── ...
    ├── vertex.cpp
    └── world.cpp
```

So what I am trying to do is just to compile the source into a shared library and then install it with the header files.

Most examples that I have found compile executables with some shared libraries but never just a plain shared library.
It would also be helpful if someone could just tell me a very simple library that uses cmake, so I can use this as an example.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam

Comment: Same question, but is there a way to maintain my sources mixed (.h ans .cpp in the same sources directory) but to let Cmake produce an include directory, product of its work?

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Always specify the minimum required version of `cmake`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
```

You should declare a project. `cmake` says it is mandatory and it will define convenient variables `PROJECT_NAME`, `PROJECT_VERSION` and `PROJECT_DESCRIPTION` (this latter variable necessitate cmake 3.9):

```
project(mylib VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "mylib description")
```

Declare a new library target. Please avoid the use of `file(GLOB ...)`. This feature does not provide attended mastery of the compilation process. If you are lazy, copy-paste output of `ls -1 sources/*.cpp` :

```
add_library(mylib SHARED
    sources/animation.cpp
    sources/buffers.cpp
    [...]
)
```

Set `VERSION` property (optional but it is a good practice):

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
```

You can also set `SOVERSION` to the major number of `VERSION`. So `libmylib.so.1` will be a symlink to `libmylib.so.1.0.0`.

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR})
```

Declare public API of your library. This API will be installed for the third-party application. It is a good practice to isolate it in your project tree (like placing it `include/` directory). Notice that, private headers should not be installed and I strongly suggest to place them with the source files.

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER include/mylib.h)
```

If you work with subdirectories, it is not very convenient to include relative paths like `"../include/mylib.h"`. So, pass a top directory in included directories:

```
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE .)
```

or

```
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE include)
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE src)
```

Create an install rule for your library. I suggest to use variables `CMAKE_INSTALL_*DIR` defined in `GNUInstallDirs`:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
```

And declare files to install:

```
install(TARGETS mylib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

You may also export a `pkg-config` file. This file allows a third-party application to easily import your library:

- with Makefile, see [`pkg-config`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config)
- with Autotools, see [`PKG_CHECK_MODULES`](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html)
- with cmake, see [`pkg_check_modules`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html)

Create a template file named `mylib.pc.in` (see [*pc(5)* manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/pc.5.html)  for more information):

```
prefix=@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@
exec_prefix=@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@
libdir=${exec_prefix}/@CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR@
includedir=${prefix}/@CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR@

Name: @PROJECT_NAME@
Description: @PROJECT_DESCRIPTION@
Version: @PROJECT_VERSION@

Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lmylib
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt`, add a rule to expand `@` macros (`@ONLY` ask to cmake to not expand variables of the form `${VAR}`):

```
configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc @ONLY)
```

And finally, install generated file:

```
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.pc DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

You may also use [cmake `EXPORT` feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-exports). However, this feature is only compatible with `cmake` and I find it difficult to use.

Finally the entire `CMakeLists.txt` should looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(mylib VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "mylib description")
include(GNUInstallDirs)
add_library(mylib SHARED src/mylib.c)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER api/mylib.h)
configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc @ONLY)
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE .)
install(TARGETS mylib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.pc
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments, to comply with standards you should be able to generate a static library as well as a shared library. The process is bit more complex and does not match with the initial question. But it worths to mention that it is greatly explained [here](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/libraries/static-shared.html).

Comment: Just complementing the @Jezz's awesome explanation: after all steps above, the programmer can build and install the library by `mkdir build && cd build/ && cmake .. && sudo make install` (or `sudo make install/strip` to install the _striped_ library version).

Comment: Do you have a technique for passing down library dependencies?  For example if mylib depended on liblog4cxx, what would be a good way of flowing that all the way through to mylib.pc?

Comment: @mpr If liblog4cxx provide a `.pc` file, add `Requires: liblog4cxx` to your `mylib.pc`, else, you can just add `-llog4cxx` to `Libs:`.

Comment: How would I use this library in another project? Could you extend your example?

Comment: And do you add all headers to PUBLIC_HEADER or only the one that other users should be able to see? If not, what do you do with all the other headers?

Comment: @DamirPorobic As explained in answer, pkg-config allow third-party applications to easily import your library. Try: pkg-config for Makefile, PKG_CHECK_MODULES for Autotools, pkg_check_modules for cmake.

Comment: @DamirPorobic only headers that other users should be able to see should be declared in  PUBLIC_HEADER. If you encounter problems, it probably means that your public API is not correctly defined.

Comment: @JérômePouiller "Please avoid use of file(GLOB ...)." Does that mean, do not use `file()` or do not use `GLOB`? For GLOB I fully understand. But "file" is way practical to manipulate or reuse lists of files multiple times.

Comment: @Sandburg AFAIK, `file()` is not necessary to manipulate list of files. `set()` seems sufficient. I am curious to have a use case.

Comment: @JérômePouiller Since I learn modern CMake, I have the reflex to think that every usage of `set()` (legacy of old CMake) have to be challenged. Because other more explicit and specialized keywords and commands have been implemented to replace direct `CMAKE_*` manipulations. But if you (looking expert) tell me it's OK to use `set()`in that case, I agree. Casual use case: `file(GLOB process_source_files ../../process/createprocess.h ../../process/createprocess.cpp)   
source_group(shared FILES ${process_source_files})   add_library(mySpecificLib STATIC ${process_source_files})`

Comment: `add_library` should be used without **STATIC/SHARED**, `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` must be used. https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/libraries/static-shared.html

Comment: @Alexis The OP explicitly asked for a shared library. However, I agree with you. BTW, the reference you have mentioned is really good.

Comment: Don't worry, I commented for reference. This question is very popular and is one of the first links on google. It's hard to find good references to follow the CMake's spirit!

Comment: Since this answer goes beyond just building a shared library, but also installing a pkg-config file, it would be even better to explain how to hide all symbols by default with CMake, how to export symbols of API, how to export CMake targets.

Answer (score 99):

This minimal `CMakeLists.txt` file compiles a simple shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (test)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_library(test SHARED src/test.cpp)
```

However, I have no experience copying files to a different destination with CMake. The file command with the COPY/INSTALL signature looks like it might be useful.

Comment: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE should be omitted, so the decision is up to the one who compiles.

Comment: Does specifying `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/` in `include_directories` is usefull?

Comment: @Jezz I don't think so, the same directory gets included without the prefix. It would matter if you were in a subdirectory, however.

Comment: And what if I want to mix my sources and my headers in a generic "source" directory? Is there a "post generation" possibility to create the "header" directory from my sources? (install commands maybe)

Answer (score 34):

I'm trying to learn how to do this myself, and it seems you can install the library like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.0)

project(mycustomlib)

# Find source files
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

# Include header files
include_directories(include)

# Create shared library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})

# Install library
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install library headers
file(GLOB HEADERS include/*.h)
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: simplest and straight-forward answer

Answer (score 27):

First, this is the directory layout that I am using:

```
.
├── include
│   ├── class1.hpp
│   ├── ...
│   └── class2.hpp
└── src
    ├── class1.cpp
    ├── ...
    └── class2.cpp
```

After a couple of days taking a look into this, this is my favourite way of doing this thanks to modern CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mylib VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  message(STATUS "Setting build type to '${DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE}' as none was specified.")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "${DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE}" CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  # Set the possible values of build type for cmake-gui
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release" "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/class1.cpp src/class2.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE src)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SOVERSION 1)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT MyLibConfig
    ARCHIVE  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(EXPORT MyLibConfig DESTINATION share/MyLib/cmake)

export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE MyLibConfig.cmake)
```

After running CMake and installing the library, there is no need to use Find***.cmake files, it can be used like this:

```
find_package(MyLib REQUIRED)

#No need to perform include_directories(...)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} mylib)
```

That's it, if it has been installed in a standard directory it will be found and there is no need to do anything else. If it has been installed in a non-standard path, it is also easy, just tell CMake where to find MyLibConfig.cmake using:

```
cmake -DMyLib_DIR=/non/standard/install/path ..
```

I hope this helps everybody as much as it has helped me. Old ways of doing this were quite cumbersome.

Comment: Perfect answer, I'd remove `PRIVATE src` from `target_include_directories` since you're not supposed to have them "global" using `#include <header.h>` , rather `#include "header.h"` as relative path.