# Trying to build shared library in CLion/CMake

Tags: c++, dll, build, cmake, clion

I've been trying to download and build the [Stanford Library](https://github.com/stepp/stanford-cpp-library/tree/master/StanfordCPPLib)  source files and build a library out of them to use for my own project using the CLion (IDE). I've been following instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511496/create-a-shared-library-with-cmake) answer and my CMakeLists file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Stanford)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)


file(GLOB MyHeaders "*.h" /stacktrace/"*.h" private/"*.h")
file(GLOB MySources "*.cpp" /stacktrace/"*.cpp" private/"*.cpp")
include_directories(MyHeaders)
add_library(Stanford SHARED ${MySources} ${MyHeaders})


target_include_directories (Stanford PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

When opening the run menu, I get the following:[image: Screenshot 1]

If I tell it to build anyway I get the following errors.

[image]

I've been struggling to find out what why I need an executable to build a library and what those undefined references mean.

Comment: `Executable` is needed only if you want to run your program in IDE(CLion). As your project contains only library, you doesn't need to specify anything in `Executable` field. As usual, undefined references means that none of your sources which built into library contains definition of these function. (Instead of `/stacktrace/` in `file(GLOB)` should be `stacktrace/`).

Comment: Oh, you're right about the executable, what's still unclear to me is why I get the undefined references, in fact the IDE(auto-complete) sees those references...

Comment: Determine source file, which defines missed functions, and check, that this file is listed in variable `MySources`. You can output value of the variable using `message()` command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but include command should look like this: `include_directories(${MyHeaders})`. `${MyHeaders}` will expand the variable `MyHeaders` and pass its current value to `include_directories`. Otherwise you are, literally, including directory `MyHeaders`.

Answer (score 0):

Standford library provide `call_stack_windows.cpp` and `call_stack_gcc.cpp`. Only one should be included.  In your case, you should use `call_stack_gcc.cpp`. `call_stack_windows.cpp` cannot link with `gcc`.

So, my answer is: don't use globbing to declare your sources. It is very error prone. If you are lazy, just copy-paste output of `find . -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h'` to your `CMakeList.txt`.

In add, there are many bad practices in `CMakeList.txt` you show. I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45843676/301717).