# C++ Shared Library to main.cpp

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm trying to include shared library in my main using CMake.

I used this example [Trying to build shared library in CLion/CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966780/trying-to-build-shared-library-in-clion-cmake) and [C++ Link two Shared Library to main.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531662/c-link-two-shared-library-to-main-cpp?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
but its not working. I am getting undefined reference to all the function call.

My directory tree is like that:

```
**folder**
| **project folder**
|      | 
|      |_main.cpp
       |_
|      |_CMakeLists.txt
|      |
| **lib**
     |_**lib1**
          |_CMakeLists.txt
          |_liblib1.so
          |_**src**
               |_lib1.cpp
          |_**include**
               |_lib1.h
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` of the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(DAL_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-lpq")
set(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lpq")

include_directories(/usr/include)
include_directories(-I/home/yaodav/Desktop/git_repo/lib/internal/conn2/include/)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")
SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp  SymbolInfo.cpp SymbolInfo.h SymbolDAL.cpp SymbolDAL.h AppSettingDAL.cpp AppSettingDAL.h AppSetting.cpp AppSetting.h)
add_executable(DAL_project ${SOURCE_FILES} )
```

I am trying to add those lines to the `CMakeLists.txt` but it is not working:

```
target_link_libraries(DAL_project conlibcon.so)
add_library(libconnlib SHARED IMPORTED -L../lib/internal/conn1)
```

Comment: Accepted answer is described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3440745) to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
project(DAL_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) 
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-lpq") 
set(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "-lpq")

include_directories(/usr/include) 
include_directories(/home/yaodav/Desktop/git_repo/lib/internal/conn2/include) 
link_directories(/lib/internal/conn1 )
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}") 
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}") 
SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp SymbolInfo.cpp SymbolInfo.h SymbolDAL.cpp SymbolDAL.h AppSettingDAL.cpp AppSettingDAL.h AppSetting.cpp AppSetting.h) 
add_executable(DAL_project ${SOURCE_FILES} )
target_link_libraries(DAL_project connlib)
```

if this not work try to do this 
add_library( LIB_NAME SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET LIB_NAME PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION FULL_PATH_TO_LIB)

Add the lib to target_link_libraries and the include files to the include_directories

Comment: where to add those lines? at the end?

Comment: I edit the answer