# Add subdirectory as a library to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

TLDR: I have two projects(Project A & B) using CMakeLists.txt, both build executables and they work separately. Now, I want to use Project A as a library in Project B, let's call this Project AB. How do I do it?

Current Directory Structures :

Project A

```
rootA
 |- bin
 |   |-
 |- build
 |   |-
 |- external-includes
 |- CMakeLists.txt with add_subdirectory(libraryA)
 |- libraryA
     |- main.cpp (uses library_A in an example program)
     |- library_A.cpp
     |- library_A.h
     |- Other .h and .cpp files library_A uses
     |- CMakeLists.txt having add_executable (library_A main.cpp library_A.cpp ....)
```

Project B

```
rootB
 |- bin
 |   |-
 |- build
 |   |-
 |- external-includes
 |- CMakeLists.txt with add_subdirectory(libraryB)
 |- libraryB
     |- main.cpp
     |- library_B.cpp
     |- library_B.h
     |- Other .h and .cpp files library_B uses
     |- CMakeLists.txt having add_executable (library_B main.cpp library_B.cpp ....)
```

Project AB

```
rootAB
 |- bin
 |   |-
 |- build
 |   |-
 |- external-includes
 |- rootA 
 |- CMakeLists.txt with add_subdirectory(libraryB)
 |- libraryB
     |- main.cpp
     |- library_B.cpp
     |- library_B.h
     |- Other .h and .cpp files library_B uses
     |- CMakeLists.txt having add_executable (library_B main.cpp library_B.cpp .....)
```

What I've tried so far:

I've tried adding `include_directories(rootA/libraryA)` and `add_sudirectory(rootA)` to rootAB/CMakeLists.txt and `#include <library_A.h>` to rootAB/libraryB/main.cpp, then it complains about linking errors(unresolved external symbol). If I add `#include <library_A.cpp>` , it will complain about other linking errors from library A, which don't occur if I build library_A separately. Probably what I want to do is to build library_A as a (static) library and link it in ProjectAB (preferably using current directory structure and modifications to CMakeLists.txt(s)). How to do so?

Comment: Perhaps you should have the ` add_library` command in the library sub-directories `CMakeLists.txt` file? Then you can use that library in a `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191635/how-to-build-libraries-with-cmake) , will try and update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191635/how-to-build-libraries-with-cmake) example, modify rootAB/rootA/libraryA/CMakelists.txt, replacing

```
add_executable (library_A main.cpp library_A.cpp ....)
```

with

```
add_library (library_A library_A.cpp ....)
```

and in rootAB/libraryB/CMakelists.txt, add

```
target_link_libraries(library_B library_A)
```