# Linker error while attempting to create my own shared library using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, linker-errors, clang++

I'm trying to build my own shared library and to build an other application to use it (nothing groundbreaking, I'm learning CMake). I have written theses CMakeLists :

#### For the lib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(MyLib LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "MyLib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++20")

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(SOURCES src/MyLibsources.cpp)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_library(MyLib SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)

#here is a reference to a static lib that I wrote and with which I have experienced no trouble for now
add_subdirectory(AKML-lib/)
target_link_libraries(MyLib PRIVATE AKML)
target_include_directories(MyLib PRIVATE src/AKML-lib/)
set_property(TARGET AKML PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

install(TARGETS MyLib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
#install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION include)
```

#### For the little applet :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(MyUtility LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++20")

#set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
find_library(MyLib NAMES MyLib.dylib PATHS "/usr/local/lib/" REQUIRED NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message(${MyLib})

set(SOURCES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(MyUtility ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(MyUtility PUBLIC MyLib)
```

**Everything build and install fine for the lib, but when I try to build my applet I encounter this message in the main file of the application : `fatal error: 'MyLibHeader.hpp' file not found in #include "MyLibHeader.hpp"`.**

#### My project structure is as follows :

**For the lib :**

```
\include\
    -> MyLibHeader.hpp
\src\
    -> MyLibsources.cpp
\AKML-lib\
    -> files of the static lib which is not today topic
CMakeLists.txt
```

**For the application :**

```
\src\
    -> main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

With the message command I have checked that CMake was actually finding the library that he does correctly.

I have tried for several hours now and I'm quite desperate. I give credit to theses previous answer that were a great help for previous debugging ([How to create a shared library with cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511496/how-to-create-a-shared-library-with-cmake)) but, for this issue, I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your help!

PS: I'm building on Macos Sonoma

Comment: A library file (`MyLib.dylib` in your case) doesn't contain information about directory where its header files reside. Aside from linking your executable with MyLib library, you need to specify include directory, e.g. with `target_include_directories` command.

Comment: `find_library` just searches for a dynamic library and returns the path. You probably want to use the [CMakePackageConfigHelpers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html) to write a MyLibConfig.cmake that you can then include with `find_package`

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for your answer! should I add target_include_directories in the CMakeLists of the application ? If I do so, I would have to link to the header files of the lib ? I was thinking that after "compiling" (I'm not sure for this term) the library, I would not have to bother anymore in the child applications with its source and header files and only use the dylib file : was I mistaking ?

Comment: "I was thinking that after "compiling" (I'm not sure for this term) the library, I would not have to bother anymore in the child applications with its source and header files and only use the dylib file : was I mistaking ?" - No, this is a false assumption. A `.dylib` file alone doesn't allow application to include a library header via `#include`.

Answer (score 0):

`find_library` won't solve any related path and resouces for you (e.g., your .h or .hpp) but just .lib in this case. You need to [exporting your target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets) and use `IMPORTED` it later on or [creating your package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#creating-packages) like @Botje said, and use `find_package` for your created package. Otherwise, you could use `add_subdirectory` to directly include your library project, but it must be located in subfolder.