Creating a DLL in CLion
I have a program for a game AI for a 3D Connect 4 game (4x4x4) in C++.
I made the same game in Unity 3D. I want to interface the game AI in C++ with my Unity project by creating a DLL that will accept player move as an int and output AI moves as int. I'll keep some static lists within the DLL function.
I can't seem to find any sources on building a DLL with Clion and it will be really difficult to shift the project to visual studio. How can I create the DLL using Clion? Are there any better approaches than using a DLL?
I believe I have to use add_library() in CMake. I'm not sure how I can do that I've looked it up and I can't seem to find anything about it.
I made a basic DLL .cpp file using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qljLhXfVt78.
this is sort of what the implementation would look like

#ifndef CONNECT_4___3D_BACKEND_H
#define CONNECT_4___3D_BACKEND_H

#define DLL_EXPORT \__declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"{
int DLL_EXPORT SimpleReturnFun(int playermove);
}

#endif //CONNECT_4___3D_BACKEND_H


#include "backend.h"

extern "C"{
int DLL_EXPORT SimpleReturnFun(int playermove){
         static int board [4][4][4];
        static int temp [2][3];
        int d = 1;
        
        int x = playermove/100; 
        int y = playermove%100/10; 
        int z = playermove%10;
        board[x][y][z] = 1;
        
        return cpuPutProc(board, d, temp);
    }
}


I believe I have to used add_library() in CMake. I'm not sure how I can do that I've looked it up and I can't seem to find anything about it. You need to create a shared library. There should be thousands of examples of how to do that with CMake. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511496/how-to-create-a-shared-library-with-cmake

I have a CMake library example at Github at: https://github.com/drescherjm/CMakeLibraryExample/tree/main

@drescherjim
Hi, I followed the link you added and appended this to my CMakeLists.
The program is being built and I can run it but I can't find any dll files.
https://gist.github.com/J999py/1d4dcbb24ab8d50c26837698b866a9fc

Copy the dlls to the same folder as the executable or set your PATH environment variable to the folder containing the dll.

This question helps with automatic copying of dlls using CMake: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake
