# How to enable cmake to exclude a subdirectory from install?

Tags: installation, cmake, clang, rpm, libc++

I have been trying to build `RPM` packages for `libc++` 3.3 on a RHEL 6.4 box. I need both static and shared libraries. So, I learned some basics of `cmake` and then modified the bundled `CMakeList.txt`. Got that part to work.

But since in RHEL 6.x, all 64-bit libraries should go to `/usr/lib64` instead of `/usr/lib`,  I have been attempting to use the following to get the job done:

(A) During building, I use

```
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
```

to have all library files (`*.so*` and `*.a`) located in `lib64` rather than `lib`.

(B) Using a `ADD_LIBRARY...` command as shown below

```
ADD_LIBRARY(c++ STATIC ...
```

together with

```
set_target_properties(c++ PROPERTIES
   ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
   INSTALL(TARGETS c++ 
         ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
```

to get the static library installed in `/usr/lib64`.

(C) In addition, with

```
INSTALL(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/libc++.so DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
INSTALL(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/libc++.so.1 DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
INSTALL(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX}/libc++.so.1.0 DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
```

to have shared libary also installed in `/usr/lib64` too.

But a copy of the shared library is still installed in `/usr/lib` in the resulting RPM.  How can I prevent it?

If I were to write a RPM `spec` file, the `_libdir` macro automatically handles this. With `cmake`, given the fact that I am still new to it, I would appreciate a hint/pointer as to the right directive to use.

Comment: Another way of posing the Q perhaps is: how do you ensure that a library is installed in /usr/lib64 on a RHEL 6.x platform - so far the most popular server platform in data centers?  One more alternative is perhaps how to use `cmake` to configure `cpack` so that a certain `%dir` is excluded from the generated `spec` file?

Comment: Can you specify: 1. the status of your build tree/location of files when you have finished building 2. where are the files after you run install 3. where you would like your files to be instead

Comment: @Antonio: Thanks for responding. Regarding your Qs: 1. status: successful build without errors. location: `$HOME/clang3.3/libs/build_libcxx` (I always use out-of-source-build); 2. `$HOME/clang3.3/libs/build_libcxx/lib64`; 3. Both shared and static libraries to `/usr/lib64`. Right now, shared library files *.so* also show up in `/usr/lib` - IMHO undesirable.

Comment: I think the tip given in this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam?lq=1 Maybe a better approach is to create my own `CMakeLists.txt`, add two libraries, install the include files,  and then be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, with a helpful person in the `cmake` mailing list, I am now able to rid of the `%dir /usr/lib` in the generated `spec` file. It's actually quite simple: just cd to `$CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR/lib` and edit the `CMakeLists.txt` there.  Append `${LIB_SUFFIX}` to the two install `DESTINATION`s. Regenerate the `Makefile` in the `build` subdirectory, and then `make && make package`. All library files go into `/usr/lib64` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see:

1) There's a missing space in `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX})`, should be `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX})`

2) When are your .so files going to be build if you use `ADD_LIBRARY(c++ STATIC ...`?

Comment: I have been thinking perhaps I should use the original `CMakeList.txt` and modify it until it install the resulting shared library in `/usr/lib64` (for a 64bit library build) instead of `/usr/lib` as it does now. But being new to `cmake`, I need to do some studies. The original doesn't have an explicit target (the `cxx` target is "implicitly" defined AFAICT).

Comment: 1) Fixed. Edited the original post. It was due to cut-n-paste. My real `CMakeLists.txt` does have the space. 2) According to my `make -j4` output, the sequence shown is: (1) `[  4%] Built target abilib_headers` (2) `[  6%] [  8%] [ 10%] Scanning dependencies of target cxx` (3) `[ 66%] Linking CXX static library lib64/libc++.a` (4) `[ 66%] Built target c++` (5) `[100%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cxx.dir/__/src/future.cpp.o`
`Linking CXX shared library ../lib64/libc++.so`