# CMake creating shared and static library with different defines

Tags: cmake

I want to create a static and a shared library using CMake to create the build environment. Furthermore it should create an `ANSI` and a `UNICODE` version.

I found this posting: [Is it possible to get CMake to build both a static and shared version of the same library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam)

which told me that I can use multiple `add_library` statements to achieve this. When I tried it, it creates the libraries fine, but the posting doesn't tell me how to set different `-D` options depending on which version is built.

My `CMakeLists.txt` currently looks like this:

```
list(APPEND SUPPORT_SOURCE
    dll_main.cpp
)

add_definitions(-DBUILD_SUPPORT_DLL)

add_library(support SHARED ${SUPPORT_SOURCE} )
add_library(support_s STATIC ${SUPPORT_SOURCE} )
add_library(support_u SHARED ${SUPPORT_SOURCE} )
add_library(support_su STATIC ${SUPPORT_SOURCE} )
```

After all, when I build the DLL, the functions needs the `__declspec(dllexport)` declaration which it should not have in the static versions. Furthermore to build the `UNICODE` variant I need to pass `-DUNICODE`.

So I need to know which version is built and use appropriate build flags for it for the various targets.

Another thing I don't understand is, how I can create debug builds with a different name. I usually use the pattern `libname.lib` and `libname_d.lib` so I can have all possible versions in a single directory to link against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set compiler flags per-target by using the [`target_compile_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_compile_definitions.html) command.  For example:

```
target_compile_definitions(support PRIVATE MY_SHARED_DEFINITION)
target_compile_definitions(support_s PRIVATE MY_STATIC_DEFINITION)
```

As for adding a postfix to your debug libraries, you can achieve this by setting the CMake variable [`CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/variable/CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX.html):

```
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX _d)
```

This will cause all non-executable targets to have `_d` appended when built in Debug.  If you need more fine-grained control, you can set the [`DEBUG_POSTFIX`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_tgt/CONFIG_POSTFIX.html) property for individual targets:

```
set_target_properties(support support_s PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX -dbg)
```

This will override the global `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` value for these two targets and give them a `-dbg` postfix instead.