# CMake: Different compile definitions for static and shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

In a project using cmake, I build two versions of a library, one statically and one dynamically linked. For a single source file, I want to pass a different compile definition (i.e. `-Dfoo=bar`) when compiling for the shared library only.

I know about `set_target_properties` where I can use the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` for a single source, but I don't know how to add that definition only for the shared library.

How can this be done?

**Edit**

To clarify how this question is different, I am already making two versions of the same library.

```
add_library(static_lib STATIC foo.cpp bar.cpp)
add_library(dyn_lib SHARED foo.cpp bar.cpp)
```

What I would like to do is to add the target property that `foo.cpp` is compiled with `-Dbaz=True` *only* when compiling `foo.cpp` for `dyn_lib`.

Comment: The common pattern I've seen in many projects is to have 2 targets - for static library and for shared one. With 2 targets you can set different flags for them.

Comment: @arrowd I'm rather ignorant of cmake. I only know how to add the source targets to the library as `add_library(${lib_name} (STATIC|SHARED) ${list of sources})`. Do you mean do some level of indirection between the name of source file and adding in the `add_library` command?

Comment: I meant, you should make 2 calls to `add_library()` - one for static lib and another for shared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get CMake to build both a static and shared version of the same library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way add the definition `-Dbaz=True` for objects compiled for the **library target** `dyn_lib` is to use [target_compile_definition()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html).

```
target_compile_definition(dyn_lib PRIVATE -Dbaz=True)
```

This effectively is a shorter version of setting `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property for `dyn_lib` target.

```
set_target_properties(dyn_lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS -Dbaz=True)
```

---

To compile a **single source file** with the definition `-Dbaz=True` use [set_source_files_properties()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html).

```
set_source_files_properties(file.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS -Dbaz=True)
```

Comment: This defines `baz` for all sources being compiled into `dyn_lib`. How would I define `baz` only for a single source?

Comment: I am a bit confused of your comment. Why would you expect symbols being valid only for specific source files, while source files generally are dependent on your target of the specific library you add? Symbols can be evaluated via prprocessor directives and they are just there (globally for a project) or not. How you use them in sources is a matter of forks in those preprocessor directives in the different sources.

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor, I added answer to your question.