# How to create a static library (.a file) in Android Studio 3.2 with CMake

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface, static-libraries

Now i create a new project include c++ support in Android Studio 3.2, it has `native-lib.cpp` naturally, the `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    native-lib

    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED

    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
    src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
```

now if i build this project, i can find `libnative-lib.so` in some "debug" directoies, that's OK, but i want static library ie `.a` files.

Change **SHARED** to **STATIC** won't generate those files, what else should i do？

The CMake docs does not mention other way than `add_library()`.

Every docs i searched only talk about `SHARED/STATIC`.

What did i miss?

Comment: _"Change SHARED to STATIC won't generate those files"_ 
 Where did you look for it? I would expect it to exist under `app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/buildVariant/abi/src/main/cpp/` (where `buildVariant` is one of your build variants, and `abi` is one of the ABIs you're building for).

Comment: You will need to *use* the static library in a shared library for it to be useful for an app. Unless you're distributing the library, a static library alone is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, i want to thank all guys above, without your inspiration, i cannot get this answer.

I write this answer down **NOT** becase those answers are wrong, i just want to help newbies like me, setp by step, with all details should know.

This answer was proved in **Android Studio 3.2.1** with **CMake 3.4.1**, i triple checked.

Now if you create a new project **with C++ support**, click "next" all the way, you will get a `CMakeLists.txt`, whick should looks like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( 
        native-lib
        SHARED
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

find_library( 
        log-lib
        log)

target_link_libraries( 
        native-lib
        ${log-lib})
```

Change **SHARED** to **STATIC** won't output any `.a` file, you will get nothing, even no `.so` file( of course, there is no **SHARED** library be added in this file).

This is **Gradle/Android Studio** 's "fault", the answers above already mentioned it, if you use **CMake** alone, you'll definetely get a `.a` file.

OK, now is my **TRICK**:

We already have a add SHARED library, then we add a STATIC library, which uses the same source file. Add below in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(
        native-lib-static
        STATIC
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
)
```

"native-lib-static" can be replaced with any name but "native-lib" since it is used for the SHARED version.

Change your `target_link_libraries` like this:

```
target_link_libraries(
        native-lib
        native-lib-static
        ${log-lib})
```

[image]

Gradle->app->build->assembleDebug/assembleRelease

Then you'll get `libnative-lib-static.a`, in

```
app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug(release)\<abi>\libnative-lib-static.a
```

This path is set in `app\build.gradle`:

```
android{
    defaultConfig{
         externalNativeBuild{
             CMake{
```

ATM i'm not sure whether Google will change it in the future, but you can always search the project folder for `*.a` files.

I don't think i miss anything this time.

All credit to @Michael @Dan Albert @Alex Cohn @shizhen

Comment: This doesn't work now for me, Android studio Version is 2020.3.1, on mac, M1 chip. The answer from Suen works for me.

Comment: this did work for me, however I found the static libraries at app/.cxx/<8char_generated_string>/<arch> (Android Studio 2020.3.1)

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @DanAlbert 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952226/create-a-static-library-a-file-in-android-studio-3-2-with-cmake#comment92814583_52952226), the question is not how useful a static library alone can be. The issue is that Android Studio via its Gradle plugin, by default, will not build a **CMake** target that is a **STATIC** library.

Luckily, you can explicitly specify the [targets](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions:targets) you want to produce, e.g.

```
android { defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { cmake {
    targets "native_staticlib"
} } } }
```

Actually, there is not much added value building the static library via integrated **externalNativeBuild**. You can achieve same if you run `cmake --build` from command line.

Answer (score 4):

explicitly state build targets in your app level build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                # state here
                targets "native-lib" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output `native-lib.a` is in both `build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/<abi>` and `.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/<abi>` directory

see [google ndk-samples](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/master/hello-libs/gen-libs/build.gradle)

Comment: This should be answer @2020

Answer (score 1):

> Change SHARED to STATIC won't generate those files, what else should i do？

You can have the static library by setting your lib as `STATIC` and the generated **`.a`** is located at `<project-dir>/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/<abi>/libnative-lib.a`

```
add_library( native-lib
         STATIC
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
```

But, like @Dan Albert said, this static lib itself is not much useful. You still need to link it with your other parts of code/libs to come out a final shared library, so that your Android app can use.

**For example**,

```
add_library(my-shared-native SHARED src/main/cpp/other-source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my-shared-native -Wl,--whole-archive native-lib -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

Then on your Java side, you can use this **shared library**, i.e. `libmy-shared-native.so`.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("my-shared-native");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What does '-Wl,--whole-archive native-lib -Wl,--no-whole-archive' mean ?

Answer (score 0):

My Android Studio Version: `Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1`

First, change `SHARED` to `STATIC` in CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

project("mystaticapplication")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        mystaticapplication

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        STATIC

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        mystaticapplication

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

And then, add the `externalNativeBuild` block to your module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=latest', '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
                targets 'mystaticapplication'
                cppFlags ''
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Finally, `Rebuild Project`, It will generate the .a file you want:

```
...\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\...\obj\arm64-v8a\libmystaticapplication.a
```

Comment: This works but the header files don't get generated. I have to run `ninja install` manually for header files to be visible. Any idea what could be wrong?