# How to add multiple cmake target to android ndk project

Tags: android, android-ndk

So I started an android ndk project, and added a new module `another_lib` in addition to the `native-lib` that comes with the new project, I have a `cmakelists.txt` file in as shown and the content is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_subdirectory(another_lib)
add_subdirectory(native_lib)
```

and for each subdirectory, i have defined a build target. then in my `build.gradle` i have

```
   externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

However, when I built the project, it only builts `native_lib`. Did i miss anything to add my own module to build?

Answer (score 1):

It is the issue that android cannot create static lib unless it is added in the build.gradle file, for me I need to add line:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        ...
        targets "native-lib", "anotherlib"
    }
}
```

Refer to here for more details on why android studio cannot build static lib
[How to create a static library (.a file) in Android Studio 3.2 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952226/how-to-create-a-static-library-a-file-in-android-studio-3-2-with-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) to `native-lib`.

```
add_dependencies(native-lib another_lib)
```