# How to install a dynamic dependency of a cmake-project?

Tags: cmake

Consider a library `frob` that can be built as shared and static library in one go. That's [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29824424/2747160) achieved with two libraries that only differ in `STATIC` / `SHARED` (c.f. setup details below). For convenience we add a third interface library (`automatic`) solely for selecting the right library version depending on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`.

That works very well when building the project itself. But the library should also be consumable from an install. In that case, the auto-detection for `automatic` does not work any more. This is due to the fact that the criterion is evaluated in the installed project, rather than the consuming one (`Frob::automatic` has a fixed dependency on either `static` or `shared` in the installed `FrobConfig.cmake`).

**Question**: How to install `Frob::automatic` s.t. it depends on either `Frob::static` or `Frob::shared` depending on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` (of a consuming project)? In other words, how to install a dynamic dependency (e.g. depending on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`)?

---

### Setup for Frob

Let's start with the very basic library setup for `frob`:

```
project(frob CXX)

# User configuration
option(FROB_BUILD_STATIC "Build statically linked library version." ON)
option(FROB_BUILD_SHARED "Build shared, dynamically linked library version." ON)

if (FROB_BUILD_STATIC)
    add_library(frob-static STATIC ...)
    set_target_properties(frob-static PROPERTIES EXPORT_NAME static)
    add_library(Frob::static ALIAS frob-static)
endif()
if (FROB_BUILD_SHARED)
    add_library(frob-shared SHARED ...)
    set_target_properties(frob-shared PROPERTIES  EXPORT_NAME shared)
    add_library(Frob::shared ALIAS frob-shared)
endif()


# For convenience, we provide an interface library to automagically select the right version 
# (depending on build setup and `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`)
add_library(frob-automatic INTERFACE)
if (FROB_BUILD_SHARED AND (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OR NOT FROB_BUILD_STATIC))
    target_link_libraries(frob-automatic INTERFACE frob-shared)
else ()
    target_link_libraries(frob-automatic INTERFACE frob-static)
endif ()
add_library(Frob::automatic ALIAS frob-automatic)
set_target_properties(frob-automatic PROPERTIES EXPORT_NAME automatic)


# Furthermore `frob` should be installable:
if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    # [...] meta data
    install(
        TARGETS frob-shared frob-static frob-automatic
        EXPORT frob
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    )
    install(
        EXPORT frob
        FILE FrobConfig.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Frob
        NAMESPACE Frob::
    )
    include(CPack)
endif()
```

---

### Setup of a consumer

Consider the consuming project `consume`

```
project(consume CXX)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

add_executable(auto Automatic.cpp)
target_link_libraries(auto Frob::automatic)
```

The above question is how to install `frob` s.t. the configuration of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` in the `consume`-ing project controls whether `auto` is linked against `Frob::static` or `Frob::shared`.

Comment: Basically you don't install this target at all, but instead provide a configuration script that creates an alias lib Frob::automatic depending on the configuration.

Comment: Sounds good! How do you install any cmake-code (in frob) that a consuming project executes upon configuration?

Comment: I'd install the configuration scripts for the static/dynamic lib to a dir where cmake does not automatically pick them up as the configuration script and add a "hand crafted" config script containing the logic in the dir where `find_package`. The cmake files provided by a boost installation does check multiple configurations for a suitable one btw; perhaps it may be worth checking out those (Note though that as of version 1.74 there was no cmake project doing the same as the boost build tool (b2)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to not install `automatic`, but provide it via an extra layer of indirection. Here are the updated project details of `frob`:

```
# [...] as above

if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    # [...] meta data
    install(
        TARGETS frob-shared frob-static # no frob-automatic any more
        EXPORT frob
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    )
    install(
        EXPORT frob
        FILE FrobConfigGenerated.cmake # new Generated suffix
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Frob
        NAMESPACE Frob::
    )
    # Here's the new layer of indirection.
    install(
        FILES FrobConfig.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Frob
    )
    include(CPack)
endif()
```

where the new `FrobConfig.cmake` contains

```
# Import central (generated) configuration details.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
include(${_DIR}/FrobConfigGenerated.cmake)

# Introduce automatic aliases
if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    add_library(Frob::automatic ALIAS Frob::shared)
else ()
    add_library(Frob::automatic ALIAS Frob::static)
endif ()
```

When a consuming project (i.e. after `find_package(Frob)`) links against `Frob::automatic` that references `Frob::shared` / `Frob::static` depending on  `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`.

Substantial credit to [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254218/how-to-install-a-dynamic-dependency-of-a-cmake-project#comment118878010_67254218).